# how to use ffmpeg programmatically?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am new to **ffmpeg**, and I have found many solutions about it are given by command lines,but not codes or functions,so my question is :

**Why does people prefer to use command lines in ffmpeg, and how can I transform the command line to codes?**

For example, the docs suggest resize your video to a specified size by:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf scale=320:240 output.avi
```

But how can I implement it in my app programmatically?

Btw, there are two libraries named **libswresample** and **libswscale** in ffmpeg, what does the "sw" stand for?

Comment: First question is about preference,  second is very vague: neither is a good fit for this site.iif you ask about converting a specific ffmpeg script to code, that would be more topical -- although you'll be expected to show your work so far.

Comment: @jku your are right,actually,I am not looking for a specific script converting,but a general relationship between the script and the codes,so that I can develop the codes with the script easily in the future.

Comment: I find the answer in book **FFmpeg Basics**,**FFmpeg** is a free software for multimedia handling,while **ffmpeg** is a command line tool ,as a part of **FFmpeg**,for video and audio encoding/decoding.see [link](http://ffmpeg.tv)

Comment: See also https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20libav*

Answer (score 4):

- The difference between rescaling and resampling:

> The [libswscale](https://www.ffmpeg.org/libswscale.html) library performs highly optimized image scaling and colorspace and pixel format conversion operations.
>
> **Rescaling**: is the process of changing the video size. Several rescaling options and algorithms are available. This is usually a lossy process.
>
> The [libswresample](https://www.ffmpeg.org/libswresample.html) library performs highly optimized audio resampling, rematrixing and sample format conversion operations.
>
> **Resampling**: is the process of changing the audio rate, for example from a high sample rate of 44100Hz to 8000Hz. Audio conversion from high to low sample rate is a lossy process. Several resampling options and algorithms are available.

- to learn how to use the ffmpeg libs download the source code from `git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git` and see the `doc/examples` directory.
  Docs are here https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/index.html
- `sw` stands for software.